# At what frequency will the reactance of a 1μF capacitor equal to the resistance of a 2kΩ resistor?

Tags: capacitor, frequency, resistance, reactance

Here is my work:

\$ R = 2000 \Omega\$

\$ X_L = 2 \pi f L = 2 \pi (1 \mu F) f = 6.28\mu F(f)\$

\$f = \dfrac{2000 \Omega}{6.28 \mu F} = 318.471MHz \$

Does this look right to everyone?

Comment: No. You seem to be confusing Xl (reactance for an inductor) with Xc (reactance for a capacitor).

Comment: The reactance of a capacitor can never equal the resistance of a resistor. Mister Pedantic told me to say that!

Answer (score 5):

No. [Hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_reactance#Capacitive_reactance):

\$X_c = \dfrac{1}{2 \pi f_c C}\$

however, you have used the expression for the reactance of an inductor.

Comment: Thanks!!!! I had a feeling my numbers were off but couldn't place why.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a "C" in your formula somewhere?

Comment: Indeed. I forgot it. jippie already added it.

Comment: Got it right .. thanks everyone for all your help                        Xc=1/2πfc was the correct answer